# VarBinary vs Image SQL Server Data Type to Store Binary Data?

Tags: sql-server

I need to store binary files to the SQL Server Database. Which is the better Data Type out of Varbinary and Image?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Since image is deprecated, you should use varbinary.

per [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) **(thanks for the link @Christopher)**

> ntext , text, and image data types will be removed in a future
>   version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new
>   development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use
>   them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.
>
> Fixed and variable-length data types for storing large non-Unicode and
>   Unicode character and binary data. Unicode data uses the UNICODE UCS-2
>   character set.

Comment: @ cmsjr: maybe because as Microsoft says: "image data type will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server."

Comment: @Ehsan I can only assume that you are not familiar with the term deprecated. In general when you say something is deprecated, you are saying it should not be used because it is going to be removed in the future. So my post and the quote you posted in your comment mean essentially the same thing.

Comment: No worries, you bring up a good point. I'll update the phrasing.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a "link-only" answer. I would call this a "succinct and correct answer to a question that includes some helpful links for those who are inclined to learn more" answer.

Comment: I will be frank and let you know that I was disinclined from making the edit because you approached it with an offensive and threatening tone. Perhaps it was not your intent to be rude, but it seemed you were being so to me. Rudeness can often lead people to dismiss otherwise good ideas. I improved the content as you suggested, but I would also ask that you give some thought to how you present your suggestions.

Comment: I wonder why Microsoft is not documenting the impact of an `ALTER TABLE`, I would imagine it is only a meta data change? Has anybody experiences with it? (Will test it later on and Report)

Comment: @eckes It is not a meta data change, it produces ridicolous large logfiles. I guess recreating the table with minimal logfgging would be faster.

Answer (score 14):

**`varbinary(max)`** is the way to go (introduced in SQL Server 2005)

Answer (score 9):

There is also the rather spiffy [`FileStream`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx), introduced in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: spiffy : *smart in appearance*?

Comment: 'rather spiffy' has a somewhat more general meaning (than just 'spiffy') in common vernacular... Most apt I think.

Comment: This question is about column formats and `FileStream` is just a storage behavior.  Filestream is implemented by using `varbinary(max)` and making changes to your sql server instance.

Answer (score 7):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql

> **image**
>
> Variable-length binary data from 0 through 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)
>   bytes. Still it IS supported to use image datatype, but be aware of:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/binary-and-varbinary-transact-sql

> **varbinary** [ ( n | max) ]
>
> Variable-length binary data. n can be a value from 1 through 8,000. max indicates that the maximum storage
>   size is 2^31-1 bytes. The storage size is the actual length of the
>   data entered + 2 bytes. The data that is entered can be 0 bytes in
>   length. The ANSI SQL synonym for varbinary is binary varying.

So both are equally in size (2GB). But be aware of:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016#features-not-supported-in-a-future-version-of-sql-server

Though the end of "image" datatype is still not determined, you should use the "future" proof equivalent.

**But you have to ask yourself: why storing BLOBS in a Column?**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/compare-options-for-storing-blobs-sql-server