# Must declare the scalar variable "@Template"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, web-services, webmethod

I have a webservice that searches the database for the stored templates. However, I get the error when running my application

> Must declare the scalar variable "@Template".

```
[WebMethod]
public Verification StuVerification (byte[] Template)
{
    cn.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblFingerprint WHERE Template = @Template)", cn);
    SqlDataReader sr = com.ExecuteReader();
    while (sr.Read())
    {
        Verification verification = new Verification()
        {
            StudentID = sr.GetInt32(0),
            StudentNumber = sr.GetString(1),
            Name = sr.GetString(2),
            Surname = sr.GetString(3),
        };
        cn.Close();
        return verification;

    }

    cn.Close();
    return new Verification();

}





Verification ver = verification.StuVerification(m_VrfMin);
Verification v = new Verification();
if (ver.StudentID > 0)
{
    // Verification v = new Verification();
    richTextBox1.Text = v.StudentNumber;
}
else
{
    richTextBox1.Text = "Verification Failed" + error;
}
```

Comment: Where is the variable declared?

Comment: I don't see any parameter value that you added in your `SqlCommand` for `@Template` parameter.

Comment: What is the datatype of the Template field in the table `tblFingerprint`

Answer (score 2):

You haven't added the SQL parameter to the SQLCommand:

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Template", TemplateObject);
```

Comment: @user3284789 You have an extra paren at the end of your statement.

Answer (score 2):

The `@Template` string in your command text is a placeholder for a parameter that you should define in your command parameters collection together with a value to pass to the database code.

```
 cn.Open();
 SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM tblFingerprint 
                                   WHERE Template = @Template", cn);
 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Template", Template);
 SqlDataReader sr = com.ExecuteReader();
```

Its value is used in the execution of your query to select the rows that will be returned by the query. However, it is not clear, from your code above what is the datatype of the field `Template` in your database table. As is, this code passes a byte array in the form of a binary datatype and this could not be the exact datatype to use for comparison against the Template field.

Seeing your comment about the Image field I could suggest to try with this (NOT TESTED)

```
 SqlParameter p = com.Parameters.Add("@Template", SqlDbType.Image);
 p.Value = Template;
 SqlDataReader sr = com.ExecuteReader();
```

This seems to be necessary because adding a value of byte[] type with AddWithValue creates automatically a SqlDbType.Binary parameter type, instead the database seems to like an SqlDbType.Image, However, read about [deprecated Image field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444072/varbinary-vs-image-sql-server-data-type-to-store-binary-data)

Comment: I was talking about the Template field in the table tblFingerPrint. It is declared as VARBINARY(MAX) in your table? If yes the code should work, if not then you need some kind of conversion

Comment: Please note that your query text is incorrect. The closing parenthesis should not be present

Comment: oh sorry. the template datetype is an image. Server was unable to process request. ---> The data types image and varbinary are incompatible in the equal to operator.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.Add parameter for @template

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblFingerprint WHERE Template = @Template)", cn);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Template", Template);
```