# How to insert images into SQL Server database table

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I have created a new SQL Server local database with a table called `drink`.
I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.

Inside the table I defined the following columns:

```
id [int], kind [varchar], year [datatime], image [image]
```

I would like to insert images into the `image` column but I don't know how to do.

I need this column, because I want to display all data in DataGridView using VB.NET

Thanks for help!

Comment: If you can change the format of the table you should really use Varbinary(Max) as Image is deprecated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444072/varbinary-vs-image-sql-server-data-type-to-store-binary-data

Comment: `image` data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me...

```
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.IO
Imports System.drawing

Module Module1

    Private Const _ConnectString As String = "your connection string here"

     Sub Main()
        Dim MyImage As Image = Image.FromFile("RandomImage.jpg")
        Dim Id As Long = 1
        SaveDrinkImage(MyImage, Id)
     End Sub

    Sub SaveDrinkImage(MyImage As Image, Id As Long)

        Dim ImageBytes(0) As Byte
        Using mStream As New MemoryStream()
                 MyImage.Save(mStream, MyImage.RawFormat)
                 ImageBytes = mStream.ToArray()
        End Using

        Dim adoConnect = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(_ConnectString)
        Dim adoCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("UPDATE [drink] SET [image]=@MyNewImage WHERE [id]=@id", adoConnect)

        With adoCommand.Parameters.Add("@MyNewImage", SqlDbType.Image)
            .Value = ImageBytes
            .Size = ImageBytes.Length
        End With
        With adoCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.BigInt)
            .Value = Id
        End With

        adoConnect.Open()
        adoCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        adoConnect.close()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 3):

Using openrowset you can insert image into database:

```
insert into tableName (id,kind,ImageColumn) 
SELECT 1,'JPEG',BulkColumn 
FROM Openrowset( Bulk '<Path of the image>', Single_Blob) as img
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches. You can store the image as a blob in the database or you can store the path (string) to the image file. There is an answer that discusses this: [Storing images in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613898/storing-images-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub SaveDrinkToDB(name As String, imageFilePath As String)
    Using cn = New SqlConnection("connection string here")
        cn.Open()
        Using cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Drink (Name, Image) Values(@Name,@Image)", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", File.ReadAllBytes(imageFilePath))
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
    SaveDrinkToDB("Milk", "c:\drink.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [database_name]
GO
INSERT INTO [schema].[tablename]([property1],[property2],[Property3],[Image])
     VALUES
           ('value','value','value','C:\pathname.jpg')
GO
```

Comment: Don't add only code to answer, explanation is also necessary