# Insert Image into Database without using openfiledialog in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

Can i know how to do Insert Image into Database without using openfiledialog in vb.net?

I want to do the function like load the database and show the image on the picture box but the image are already exists in database. i have no ideas to do insert into another database with the image. I mean i just load the image from database and showing in the picture box. after that, i want to insert the same image to another database.  I am trying to find the way to do but most of the ways are only using browse by using OpenFiledialog for the image and insert into database. i cant do the way is straight forward to load the image from the database in picture box and click one button and insert the same image to another database.

I need for help please ...

Comment: There are gobs of posts here covering that.

Comment: But can i have some of example for me to look?

Comment: Are you asking us to Google for you? Sorry, you have to do some research yourself.

Comment: Do you know how to get an image from a database?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175209/retrieve-images-from-sql-server-database

Comment: Please read following posts: - [How to insert image in mysql database using vb.net and adodb connection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924982/how-to-insert-image-in-mysql-database-using-vb-net-and-adodb-connection) - [How to insert images into SQL Server database table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29439438/how-to-insert-images-into-sql-server-database-table)

Comment: thx for ur example