# Convert table column data type from image to varbinary

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, alter-table

I have a table like:

```
create table tbl ( 
  id int,
  data image
)
```

It's found that the column `data` have very small size, which can be stored in `varbinary(200)`

So the new table would be,

```
create table tbl ( 
    id int,
    data varbinary(200)
)
```

How can I migrate this table to new design ***without loosing the data in it.***

Comment: I suggest you to use `varbinary(max)` ;).

Comment: `max(DATALENGTH(data))` is well `less than 50`

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444072/varbinary-vs-image-sql-server-data-type-to-store-binary-data) ;).

Comment: First change it to `varbinary(max)`, *then* change the length as a separate step. See [ALTER TABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190273.aspx): "The data type of **text**, **ntext** and **image** columns can be changed only in the following ways ... **image** to **varbinary(max)**"

Comment: Thanks for the link; but how to convert from `image` to `varbinary(max)` with out loosing the data in the table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do two separate [`ALTER TABLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190273.aspx)s, since you can only convert `image` to `varbinary(max)`, but you can, afterwards, change its length:

```
create table tbl ( 
  id int,
  data image
)
go
insert into tbl(id,data) values
(1,0x0101010101),
(2,0x0204081632)
go
alter table tbl alter column data varbinary(max)
go
alter table tbl alter column data varbinary(200)
go
select * from tbl
```

Result:

```
id          data
----------- ---------------
1           0x0101010101
2           0x0204081632
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use this ALTER statement to convert existing column `IMAGE` to `VARBINARY(MAX)`. [Refer Here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic914594-149-1.aspx)

```
ALTER Table tbl ALTER COLUMN DATA VARBINARY(MAX)
```

After this conversion, you are surely, get your data backout.

NOTE:- Don't forgot to take backup before execution.

The IMAGE datatype has been deprecated in future version SQL SERVER, and needs to be converted to VARBINARY(MAX) wherever possible.

Answer (score 1):

How about you create a `NewTable` with the `varbinary`, then copy the data from the `OldTable` into it?

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[NewTable] ([id], [data])
            SELECT  [id], [image] FROM  [dbo].[OldTable]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all from BOL:

> image: Variable-length binary data from 0 through 2^31-1
>   (2,147,483,647) bytes.

The image data type is essentially an alias for varbinary (2GB), so converting it to a varbinary(max) should not lead to data loss.

But to be sure:

1. back up your existing data
2. add a new field (varbinary(max))
3. copy data from old field to new field
4. swap the fields with sp_rename
5. test
6. after successful test, drop the old column