# The character string is too long. Maximum length is 4000 when inserting image in sql server

Tags: sql-server, angular, image-uploading

I'm developping an angular 4 application.
I'm actually trying to insert an image in sql server , with type "image".
I'm using C# Web service, and angular 4 for front end.

I have an input type file that users needs to upload profile photo. 
I'm using this code to retrieve the path of the selected photo :

```
<input  id="profile-image-upload"  type="file" (change)="onChange($event)">

 onChange(event) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let image = this.img.nativeElement;
    reader.onload = function(e: any) {
        let src = e.target.result;
        console.log(src);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
  }
```

THE source is the path of the photo , and its like this way :

```
"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAA..."
```

**The length of the string is more than 4000.**
I can't get the full path because i searched and founded that navigator don't allow that for security.

And then when i tried to insert it in sql server with that code :

```
insert into users (imageColumn)
SELECT BulkColumn 
FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'image..Path..here', Single_Blob) as img
```

I got that error.
I tried another way to get the relative path of the image , i couldn't.

Any help ?

Comment: sql server has a limitation of 4000 characters. You can split your string based on multiples of 4000 and then concatenate them later

Comment: I suggest that store the image urls in db and store the true images in somewhere else.

Comment: actually i cant retrieve image url with angular 4 . the image is loaded from desktop and the path is that one i suggested : "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAA..."

Comment: @Vamshi Gudipati 
i cant concatinate them , 
insert into users (imageColumn)
SELECT BulkColumn 
FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'image..Path..here', Single_Blob) as img

the query needs image path so either when i will concatenate it , it will respond with the same error

Comment: ["Since image is deprecated, you should use varbinary."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444072/varbinary-vs-image-sql-server-data-type-to-store-binary-data)

Comment: Guys ! the problem is in the string of the query ! it is not for the image type image or varbinary ! the query is the same, inserting with BULK ! and its always the same error

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using nvarchar to stored the image. Can you use varbinary instead.

Comment: no i'm using type image in sql server ! and the problem in in the query not in type of image "Bulk 'image..Path..here'" , the image path must be a string with 4000 max length

Comment: Screen shots of the error would get clearer of your problem.