# Document saved to an image column gets corrupted when retrieved

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-word

I am saving documents (`*.docx, *.doc, *.pdf`) to an `Image` column in a SQL Server 2012 database. Here is the partial table script (for brevity, I removed a lot of columns)

```
[DocId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[DocDate] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
[DocName] [varchar](255) NOT NULL  DEFAULT (''),
[DocObject] [image] NOT NULL
```

The documents are being saved using this code in C#

```
using (Stream docStream = UploadResume.PostedFile.InputStream)
{
    Int32 docSize = (Int32)docStream.Length;
    byte[] docBytes = new byte[docSize + 1];
    docStream.Read(docBytes, 0, docSize);
    SaveDoc(docId, UploadResume.PostedFile.FileName.Trim(), docBytes);
}
```

SaveDoc is a procedure that inserts the data into the table. I removed code for saving other fields of data for brevity.

I am retrieving data into a DataTable (dt). I am saving the contents of the document to file system using the following C# code:

```
byte[] docBytes = (byte[])(dt.Rows[0]["DocObject"]);
var fileName = dt.Rows[0]["DocName"].ToString();
File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, $"Documents\\{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")}"), $"{fileName}"), docBytes);
```

I am able to save an MS Word document to the db, retrieve it from the db and save it to file system successfully. However when I open the document in MS Word, I get an error message indicating that the file is corrupted. PDF files are save and open fine without issues. Microsoft Word documents are not.

Comment: Probably not helpful to your current situation, but [FYI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444072/varbinary-vs-image-sql-server-data-type-to-store-binary-data)

Comment: Why `docSize + 1`?  You're adding a byte to the end.

Comment: `image` data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: As a hint, you can save one stream to another with a handy [CopyTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto?view=netcore-2.1#System_IO_Stream_CopyTo_System_IO_Stream_) method.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all of your help. I put the extra byte for testing something else and forgot to remove it later. That was the problem. I removed it and all works fine. I know that the image column type is deprecated. However, the database is part of a third party commercial product and can't be modified without breaking the commercial application. Thanks for pointing out though. Appreciate it. I can't yet accept the answer and vote since I don't have enough reputation points.