# Converting Blob Data (PDF) from SQL Database to a PDF-File

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, blob

In my Datebase Table the PDFs are saved as Blob Data, example:

[image]

What I'm trying to do now is to create a PDF file out of this data.

My code is like that:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        con.Open();
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        { 
            string query = // fancy SELECTION string goes here... reads only one by the way

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])reader["File BLOB-Contents"];
                        Console.WriteLine(bytes.Length); // prints the correct file size in Bytes
                        using (FileStream fstream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\myUsername\Desktop\test3.pdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                        {
                            fstream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The pdf gets created in the end but the problem is, that I can't open it. I get the following (German) message in Adobe Reader:

[image: Database View]

Anyone here an idea or is there something I'm doing wrong? The file size is ok. It's not 0.

Comment: The datatype for the column is `image` when it probably should be `varbinary`.  I wonder if that is the issue.  the `image` data type also should probably be avoided https://stackoverflow.com/a/444092/6530134

Comment: Pdf files start with "%PDF-" so this blob data is not a pdf file.

Comment: @KlausGütter That's a good hint. Then maybe it's encoded in some way. Ok, so nothing I can do here. Thanks for the comments anyway.

Answer (score 1):

When we storing something like a PDF file in SQL Server, I would recommend converting the PDF file into a byte array and then put it into a column that is `varbinary(max)` instead of `image`.

Honestly, I think the recommended way of doing this is having the file reside not in the DB, but instead in either local file storage or some storage service like an AWS S3 bucket and have the location be stored in the database instead.

Comment: Good advice, but this is more a comment than an answer to the question.

Comment: Would the suggestion to change the column type not solve the issues?

Comment: Yes I know all that. It's the database of our software, so its structure is not designed by us. We have to live with that. :)

Comment: Is this a problem just for that one record? What if you uploaded a sample PDF file to replicate the issue? Maybe that record is not a valid PDF in the first place ‍♂️

Comment: No that goes for every record. And when we open the PDF via the software, it works of course. So I assume it must be decoded on the fly.